# Angular - loading config.json before loading imports

Tags: angular, ngrx

Is there a dynamic approach to set up or include the StoreDevtoolsModule in Angular during runtime? Alternatively, is there a method to load a JSON file prior to the imports within the app.module?

I would like to hide Redux DevTools on production. Now I use config.json to overwrite variables in my application and I don't want to use environment.ts for this.

I would like to know if it is possible to load config.json before loading imports.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the config before the bootstrap happens:

```
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { createAppConfig } from './app/app.config';
 
//  this can also be an endpoint
// (just make sure that the endpoint is publically available, also for anonymous users)
fetch('./assets/environment-config.json')
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then((config) => {
    bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, createAppConfig(config));
  });
```

For more info see my blog https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/angular-build-once-deploy-to-multiple-environments , or the version for the standalone API https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/multiple-releases-using-the-same-but-configurable-angular-standalone-application-build

For the DevTools you can also follow this recipe within the docs https://ngrx.io/guide/store-devtools/recipes/exclude